# Как сделать автоматическое всплывание поп-апа только на определенных страницах в wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Существует такая задача,открывать поп-ап регистрации при условии что пользователь не зашел на свой аккаунт на сайте(это реализовано),но данный поп-ап не надо показывать на всех страницах сайта,а нужно только на некоторых,как подобное исполнить в wordpress(Version 4.9.5)?

function.php

```
function ajax_check_user_logged_in() {
echo is_user_logged_in()?'yes':'no';
die();
}
```

javascript(jquery)

```
var data = {
action: 'is_user_logged_in'
};
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response == 'yes') {
        // user is logged in, do your stuff here 

    } else {
        // user is not logged in, show login form here
        jQuery('#registration').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Используйте window.location.href - это текущий url. Сравните с нужными url.

Comment: К сожалению мне нужно только кусочек урла по типу sitename/store/... и всё что после store нужно делать с поп-апом

Comment: Вы не можете выделить подстроку из строки на js? Тогда вам помочь невозможно, поскольку неизвестно точное условие задачи ("нужно только на некоторых").